# Importxml returning imported content is empty

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I have used the code

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.propertyguru.com.sg/listing/hdb-for-sale-207-bishan-street-23-21890867","//div[@class='listing-title']")
```

initially it was working, however, it became imported content is empty.

I was thinking that it could be the website is blocking **scraping**, sometimes when i scroll through it site, it will ask me to verify that i am not a bot.

any thoughts?

Comment: It seems that the tag of div which has `listing-title` is not used in the HTML. So can I ask you about the result you expect?

Comment: Originally you may have had it cached because you scrolled through it, but I think once the cache expired the normal behavior kicked in: I think elements of the page aren't loaded until a scroll event happens. I'm not on my computer so I can't confirm that.

Comment: I expect to get the address of the `class='listing-title'`. It was working previously then it stopped. I asked someone to help with it and it was working on his sheet, I used his sheet and duplicate another sheet and it works also, but the next day all the sheets stopped working as well.

Answer (score 1):

looks like this won't be possible due to some overlay window which is accessed firts. you can see this if you run "get everything" command:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.propertyguru.com.sg/listing/hdb-for-sale-207-bishan-street-23-21890867",
 "//*")
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]